# Как в Java работает объявление кода в классе?

Tags: java

Я пришел из языка в PHP и мне не совсем понятно следующее. Я привык что в классе мы может лишь объявить свойства, методы, магические методы. Но здесь можно объявить сразу код. Подскажите пожалуйста как это работает?

```
Class A { 
System.out.println("Hello world!");
new A();
}
```

Comment: то что вы написали, это не правильно. Так делать нельзя.

Comment: Можно объявить блок, инитиализации. или же внутренний класс например, но это не то что вы написали.

Comment: Почитали бы вы про синтаксис языка и не было бы таких вопросов. Это не php при чем далеко не php. Тут есть свои правила написания кода - https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf

Comment: Изучайте синтаксис http://proglang.su/java/syntax. А потом уже идите дальше. (но еще лучше не трогать джаву после php) Это как небо и земля.

Comment: Я недавно видел что в теле класса был код. Возможно я ошибся. Спасибо за ссылки. Буду смотреть

Answer (score 5, accepted):

То что вы хотели написать, могло бы выглядит так:

```java
public class HelloWorld {
    // Блок static инитиализации
    static {
        System.out.println("Привет я static инитиализация, буду выполненна только один раз");
    }

    // Блок инитиализации
    {
        System.out.println("Привет я просто инитиализация, и буду выполненна всегда при создание класса");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Привет я main");
        // создаем объект
        new HelloWorld();
        new HelloWorld();
    }
}
```

ouput:

```
Привет я static инитиализация, буду выполненна только один раз
Привет я main
Привет я просто инитиализация, и буду выполненна всегда при создание класса
Привет я просто инитиализация, и буду выполненна всегда при создание класса

Process finished with exit code 0
```

тут можно прочитать [подробнее](https://vertex-academy.com/tutorials/ru/bloki-inicializacii-v-java-chast-1/)